# Failed to injected LinearLayout using dagger 2?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

Hi i am trying to inject a LinearLayout using dagger 2.11 and i get the following error:

```
Error:(12, 2) error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
public abstract interface ApplicationComponent extends dagger.android.AndroidInjector<dagger.android.DaggerApplication> {
                ^
      android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager is injected at
          com.MyClass.linearLayoutManager
      com.MyClass is injected at
          dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(arg0)
```

Here is my application Module

```
 @Module
    companion object {

   @Provides
    @Singleton
        @JvmStatic
        fun provideApplicationContext(application: MyApplication): Context = application

        @Provides
        @Singleton
        @JvmStatic
        fun provideSharedPreference(application: MyApplication): SharedPreferences =
                application.getSharedPreferences(PIANO_PREFERENCE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)

        @Provides
        @Singleton
        @JvmStatic
        fun provideInputManagerService(application: MyApplication): InputMethodManager =
                application.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager

//below doesnt work but the above works fine
  @Provides
        @Singleton
        @JvmStatic
        @Named(DagConstants.HORIZONTAL_LAYOUT_MANAGER)
        fun provideVerticalLinearLayout(application: MyApplication): LinearLayoutManager =
                LinearLayoutManager(application, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)

        @Provides
        @Singleton
        @JvmStatic
        @Named(DagConstants.VERTICAL_LAYOUT_MANAGER)
        fun provideHorizontalLinearLayout(application: MyApplication): LinearLayoutManager =
                LinearLayoutManager(application, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false)


}
```

MyClass:

```
 @Inject
    @Named(DagConstants.VERTICAL_LAYOUT_MANAGER)
    lateinit var linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager
```

fails injecting the linearLayout but everything else is injected and works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to target the annotation at the field by using `@field:Named`:

```
@Inject
@field:Named(DagConstants.VERTICAL_LAYOUT_MANAGER)
lateinit var linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager
```